Object detection but only classification and not drawing bbox
I need to train a model that can tell what are the objects in the image but don't need to draw the bbox. Does my dataset still need bbox information?
Example of the inference function ->
inference("image.jpg") returns dog, cat, horse

This is a multi-label image-classification problem, i.e. one image can have more than one label.
For such a task, no bounding boxes are needed.
